# Character class has duplicated range

Tags: regex

The regex is: `[%{1,2}|\/\/]`

This matches `%`, `%%` and `//`

FYI: this is a warning generated from flycheck.

Comment: Wait. That regex wouldn't match your given string. What are you trying to ask?

Comment: I want to match the comments which begin with `%` or `%%` or `//`. I tested it and it does match.

Comment: You probably want to change the square brackets to round parentheses. What's your question anyway?

Comment: @goofansu: Whats your input string and expected output?

Comment: Input String is like: `// a comment` or `%% this is a comment`

Comment: @NicoSchertler Yes, I tested with `/\/\/|%{1,2}/` and the warning went away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The warning means that you have duplicates in your character class. When you put something between square brackets, it means "one of those": `[abc]` means any of a, b or c. `[a|b]` means any of `a`, `|` or `b`.

So when you do `[\/\/]`, you mean "either `/`, or `/`" which is obviously a duplicate. For the same reason, `[%{1,2}]` means "either `%` or `{` or `1` or `,` or `2` or `}`" which is clearly not what you want.

The group selector are parenthesis, not square brackets, so use this regex instead:

```
(%{1,2}|\/\/)
```